# How to draw text on PDFKit's PDFView's background

Tags: cocoa, pdfkit, pdfview

I Want to write a text message, typically "Drag & Drop a PDF here" on PDFView's "background" view. By background view I mean the matte gray view displayed when no PDF document is set.

Based on documentation, I was only able to change the background color (default is gray) using

```
(void)setBackgroundColor:(NSColor *)newColor
```

Any idea how to implement this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add an extra view (text or image) and make it invisible when a PDF document is set.

Comment: Thanks it worked, I figured out how to use Z-indexes and bring the Label to the front. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Based on Willeke answer, I was able to put a label on top on my PDF view using the Z indexes.

In interface builder, the lower the item in the list, the higher the z index.
Thus in my example, I dragged and dropped the label under the PDFView.
Note: you need to launch the application to see the result, the preview will not show the label.